# Android: Listview inside ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I want to have a layout that can scroll and a listview inside it. 
The listview will expand it's height base on how many items in it. Only the ScrollView outside is scrollable.
This is my code:

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/layout_box"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/layout_height_small"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/list_regist_box_content"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_registed_box"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_add_regist_box"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:text="@string/add_regist_box"
                        android:textColor="#0F88FF"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_large"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/amount"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/common_row_height"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_bg_grey_border_bottom"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/list_regist_description"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin_medium"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/layout_width_medium"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/total"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />
                </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But the listview is neither expanded nor scrollable.

Please help!

Comment: don't put listview inside scrollview.

Comment: Liistview is scrollable if it has more items

Comment: A `ListView` is scrollable itself

Comment: The most reliable solution, IMHO, is to put your other content into rows of the `ListView`, using a suitable adapter (e.g., my `MergeAdapter`) or header/footer views, and get rid of the `ScrollView`. Beyond that, there are many, many duplicates of this question, as can be seen in the "Related" column on the right side of this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put ListView inside ScrollView - first rule of android clud :)
Instead you can use simple LinearLayout and manage you ListView items inside it.
Or you can add Header/Footer Views to the ListView and using it without scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it **is** possible to put a `ListView` inside of an `ScrollView`. In some use cases (e.g. dynamic menus/submenus it's a reasonable solution). However, two caveats apply:

- The ListView won't have scroll. In general, nested scrolling is not possible in Android. There are some hacks to make it work (mostly by using `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()`) but it's hard to make them work correctly in all cases.
- As a consequence, you must indicate the exact height the ListView needs to show all items (via its appropriate `LayoutParams`). Setting `WRAP_CONTENT` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I used below lines of code to scroll list item inside scroll view. It's working fine for my requirement, i hope it will help you.

Thanks, 
Murali.M

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            //pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```